# Client certificate browser prompt in IIS

Tags: iis, client-certificates

I need to read the certificate off a smart card reader from a web browser.
The certificate will then be used in a subsequent API call to an external service.

I have setup an asp net api project.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
{
    var cert = await HttpContext.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync();
    // call external service
    return Ok();
}
```

I have added the following in applicationHost.config

```
<section name="iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />

<security>
    <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
    <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" />
        <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true">
        </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
</security>
```

When I call the endpoint from a browser, I get the error

```
 HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden
 The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets  
 Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes.
```

How can I get the browser to prompt for the client certificate from my smart card ?
Do I need to install a certificate on my machine ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below workaround :

- Install the certificate under the root CA folder.
- Set up clientCertificateMappingAuthentication to false.
- Set the certificate hash and username password in is client certificate mapping authentication.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. Where do I get the certificate from ? Do I necessarily need one to read a smart card ?

Comment: @ThunderDev here is the documentation that mentioned if you re receiving 403.7 that means the certificate is not listed under the trusted root certificate folder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/errors-403-7-reject-client-certificate-rquest